# How to calculate diameter at multiple points of an object using image pixels?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, pixel, contour

I am trying to get diameters on different points of a cylinder over a certain length using computer vision to replace the use of optical micrometer.

Image of a cylinder:
[image]

How can I calculate the diameter of this object (cylinder) on multiple points (blue lines) along its length as shown in the image using OpenCV python?

Comment: Threshold so object is black on white background. Then invert. Then do np.count_nonzeros() for each column.

Comment: @fmw42 I can calculate no.count_nonzeros() for the whole image using edge detection algorithm but I don’t know how can I define each column (i.e., each black lines). One way might be calculating distance of each line from X and Y axis followed by finding the pixels at those distances. But I want it to be automated. For example, automatic diameter measurement at multiple points over 1cm length of the cylinder.

Comment: Specify the axis you want in np.count_nonzeros(). Axis is an argument.

Comment: I provided a question to your previous use-case. Before your post edit. Consider spending more time refining you question before you make people loose their valuable time @samitchakraborty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An OpenCV solution. The main idea is to:

1. Detect edges
2. Find the contours of the edges
3. Fill in the contour areas
4. Go through each column in the image and count the nonzero pixels

1., 2. and 3. could possibly be simplified by a single thresholding step depending on your use case

```py
import numpy as np 
import cv2


src = cv2.imread('/path/to/src.jpg')
mask = np.zeros(src.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
w, h, c = src.shape

# edge detection
threshold = 100
gray = cv2.Canny(src, threshold, threshold * 2)

cv2.imshow('', gray)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(gray, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
threshold_area = 0.5

# fill area withing contours with white color
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > threshold_area:
        cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], -1, (255, 255, 255), -1)

cv2.imshow('', mask)
cv2.waitKey(0)

# get non zero values (height) of each column
column_pixels = [cv2.countNonZero(mask[:, i]) for i in range(0, w)]
print(column_pixels)
```

Src image:

[image]

Canny result:

[image]

After filling in contours with white color:

[image]

countNonZero is applied on this last image for each column

Comment: How to convert the width/ diameter in pixels to width/diameter in mm unit? Will it be affected by change in distance from camera to object?

Comment: You need know how many mm a pixels is

Comment: 1 pixel = 0.2645833333 mm

Comment: You have the nonZero pixels in each column. Multiply all the values in that list by 0.2645833333 and you will have the mm each pixel column corresponds to

Comment: I have already done that part. For example, for  non-zero pixels I have used sum of non-zero pixels/len(non-zero pixels), which gave me an average of 2.488 pixels for the thresh of a given image. Then I multiplied it with 0.2646 to get mm. But the question is, if the distance between object and  camera changes, will it affect the dpi? Will the formula of pixels to mm will be different then? I have read this related article- "https://pyimagesearch.com/2016/03/28/measuring-size-of-objects-in-an-image-with-opencv/". But I don't have any known object size like what has been mentioned in this link.

Comment: If you change the camera distance to the object the amount of surface that each of the pixel amounts for will change as well. Changing your 1pixel==0.26… relationship